# Pronunciation of Indexed Collection of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, pronunciation

I'm currently learning about sets and I want to discuss the material. However, I'm unsure of the pronunciation of certain symbols.

For instance, I know that

(1) $A\cup B$ is read, "A union B."
(2) $A\cap B$ is read, "A intersection B."

However, I'm unsure about the pronunciation of symbols for the difference of two sets, an indexed collection of sets, and its union (or intersection). How are the following symbols pronounced when discussed with another person?

(3) $A-B$

(4) $\{S_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$

(5) $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}S_\alpha$

(6) $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

(3) "$A$ minus $B$", or "$A$ setminus $B$";

(4) "the family of the $S$-sub-$a$, for $a$ in $I$", or "the family $S$-sub-$a$, $a$ in $I$";

(5) "union of [the] $S$-sub-$a$, [for] $a$ in $I$";

(6) "union of [the] $A$-sub-$i$, [for] $i$ equals $1$ to $n$".

Words in brackets are optional — sometimes you might say them, sometimes not, depending on where in a sentence the phrase occurs.

Comment: In my experience, many people don't pronounce the "sub"s. It's a toss-up really, whether pronouncing them makes things more or less clear - depends on the expression.

Comment: What do you think about reading (4) as "the set of all S-$\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is in I?" (I've dropped the 'sub' part.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber True, that. I pronounce them silently but probably not so often aloud. Mostly it depends upon clarity, sound, & the speaker's preference.

Comment: And also, what do you think about reading (6) as, "the union of all A-i, as i goes from 1 to n?"

Comment: @K.Hotz The model of your proposal is fine, but (4) isn't "the **set** of all S-$\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is in $I$", which would be $\{S_{\alpha}\mid \alpha\in I\}$. That is the *range* of the thing displayed in (4), which is a *function*, i.e. a family. So, "the **family** of [all] S-$\alpha$, [where] $\alpha$ is in $I$", using either "where", "for" or neither. No objection to that.

Comment: @K.Hotz Re (6), I find that verbose. It's correct, but consumes a lot of breath & attention.

Comment: $A\cap B$ is also "A intersect B" (which is briefer to say)....$A-B$ is also written $A\backslash B$ and is also "A not B".

Answer (score 1):

I talk pretty casually, so these phrases might be a little out of place if you're doing a presentation or a conference. But if you're just talking with a friend, these should suffice:

(3) "$A$ minus $B$" or "$A$ setminus $B$"

(4) "[the set of] all the $S$-$\alpha$s"

(5) "the union of $S$-$\alpha$ for $\alpha$ in $I$" or if $I$ is easy to infer, "the union of all the $S$-$\alpha$s"

(6) "the union of $A_1$ through $A_n$"

Since these are usually pretty involved to say/write, you'll usually be assigning some other variable to these sets. In that case, I'll sometimes shift these phrases to use verbs:

"Next, union all the $S$-$\alpha$s together and call that $T$."